# Trying to get the minimum length in a Regex for numbers and special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

New here was recommended here.

Here goes I have 2 expressions I want to get the minimum length where if the variable has at least 2 numbers within the standard [0-9] mark and for having at least 2 spcial characters.

Here is the code I am using for testing.

```
var noOfNumerics = /[0-9]/g; 
var noOfSplChats = /[~\!@#\$%\^&*_\-\+=`\|\\(\)\{\}\[\]:;"'<>,\.\?\/]/g;
```

And here is the code that does the actual test. I have looked at tutorials and as far as i can see i see requirements that have a minimum and a maximum but I don't want a max really but If thats not possible I am okay with that.

```
var numericsTest=noOfNumerics.test(Password);
var splCharTest=noOfSplChats.test(Password);
```

Here is an example of an input that it would process as wrong.

```
Password = 'test#1';
```

Basically that is it. just need to add a length of at least 2 numbers and special characters. How would I add that requirement to my script?

Comment: Can you add an example of inputs (strings that your code should process) and desired outputs here?

Comment: like this: `/\d{2}/g` this stands for two digits

Comment: An example would be like password = 'test#1'; It should show that it failed because there is only 1 symbol and 1 Number used for the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
var noOfNumerics = /.*\d.*\d.*/g;
```

Same thing you can do it for noOfSplChats

just replace `\d` from the above regex with ``` [~\!@#\$%\^&*_\-\+=``\|\\(\)\{\}\[\]:;"'<>,\.\?\/] ```

Comment: what about the [0-9] do i add that after /.*\d.*\d.*/ or before it?

Comment: `[0-9]` is `\d`..its a short form for `[0-9]`

Comment: yup..replace \d by the special characters

Comment: So it would be like this then?
var noOfSplChats = /.*\~\!@#\$%\^&*_\-\+=`\|\\(\)\{\}\[\]:;"'<>,\.\?\/.*\~\!@#\$%\^&*_\-\+=`\|\\(\)\{\}\[\]:;"'<>,\.\?\/.*/g;

Seems like it is giving me a error

Comment: Wow, and that's how the cookie crumbles thank you very much for the help, would give you a "vote up" but not high enough sorry but thank you :)

Comment: Are you sure this returns the number of numerics? It looks like it's going to return the number of _pairs_ of numerics...

Answer (score 2):

Use lookaheads:

```
/^(?=.*\d.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$].*[!@#$])/
```

Comment: How would I add this to my script would i add this to my variables noOfNumerics and noOfSplChats or on the test varibles?

Comment: Ah, I returned too late. You see, you don't need to store the number of numerics and special characters, because the ``test`` function will already validate that. For example, ``if (/^(?=.*\d.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$].*[!@#$])/.test(password)) { return true; } else { return false; }``: that's all you need! Well, of course, add the rest of your special characters in.

Answer (score 2):

This has the advantage of being able to adjust the number of characters you require in the future.

```
function isValidPassword (p) {
    var numDigits = p.match(/\d/g).length;
    var numSpecial = p.match(/[~\!@#\$%\^&*_\-\+=`\|\\(\)\{\}\[\]:;"'<>,\.\?\/]/g).length;
    return numDigits >= 2 && numSpecial >= 2;
}
```

If you needed to search really long strings, you could use a loop with [RegExp.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) and exit as soon as you get your count

Comment: That it does. I have to say I like this option seems easy to implement and can be adjusted for the future.